# Reference to Object Within Closure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, closures

I am using React & the below code will be easier to understand for someone with React experience, however, this is a javascript question. The component (object) is created using new es2015 classes syntax.

In the below code, as soon as the object is rendered (within DOM), I am binding `onmousemove` handler (React specific info: in method `componentDidMount`).

```
classSVGParent extends Component{
     ...

     componentDidMount(){
        ....
        this.mainSVGEle.onmousemove = this.throttledMouseMoveHandler();
        // one specific detail for non-react devs : the method above 
        // 'componentDidMount' is called only once the component renders.
     }

     // the purpose of below func is to localise & create closure for the
     // actual handler function (which is returned by this method to the
     // 'onmousemove' event listener we appended above).
     throttledMouseMoveHandler(){
        let { svgState,
              ... } = this.props;
        return( function( e ){
          // when this func actually runs, it always returns `false`
          // even when the actual svgState.mousemoveState is `true`
          console.log( svgState.mousemoveState );
        });
        ...
     }
```

As per above code, in my code, I am immediately invoking the function `throttledMouseMoveHandler` upon component render. The purpose of this function is to create a closure with infomation that is needed upon each subsequent `mousemove` call.

What I expected: I expected svgState (that I am localising within 'throttledMouseMoveHandler') would hold `reference` to the prop 'svgState', & when mousemove is called, the prop value of svgState.mousemoveState would be retrieved from the original obj holding the values.

What I am experiencing: The svgState.mousemoveState never changes. Even when I can see that the original object svgState.mousemoveState is `true`, I still get `false` as returned value. This is quite surprising to me.

My question is apologetically quite open, what is the cause of this. Surely, a copy of the state object is not being stored within the closure and the connection is `live`, correct?

I did a quick example below to illustrate my understanding.

```
var aobj = { a : 1 }

var bobj = function(){
 var aref = aobj;
 return( function(){
  console.log( "aref is...", aref.a);
 });
}

var bfunc = bobj();
bfunc(); // returns `aref is... 1`, which is expected

aobj.a = 2

bfunc() // returns `aref is... 2`, which is also expected
        // so clearly the reference to external obj is live
```

Comment: The main problem is that `this` inside the event handler will not be a reference to your object; it'll be a reference to the DOM element. You can use `.bind()` when setting up the event handler.

Comment: @Pointy `this` is only used in `throttledMouseMoveHandler`. This only creates the actual event handler `return(function( e ){ ... })` which doesn't use `this`

Comment: oh I see, yes you're right.

Comment: What is stopping you from returning an arrow function and getting the props inside of the arrow function? Also note that in your examples, you are not using destructuring or let, but rather var (though I don't think that destructuring would cause a problem)

Comment: Wouldn't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fartzfvf/) be more like a sample code for your statement?

Comment: Kayote, doesn't that depend on what happens with the props itself? The sample code I supplied change the props for example, which means only the old object is kept, I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fartzfvf/1/) a bit to reflect that. Any chance you could tell us more about what state management is behind your props? If shouldComponentUpdate is called or something similar?

Comment: @Icepickle, I understand what you did there. Thank you, the obj is rewritten in your example, while in mine, the value within in overwritten. Both have different results. I suspect, thats what going on here.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I meant when I mentioned that the example code is different from the live code :) You could however take my example code to add it to your question, but that would negate the live reference fact :)

Comment: @Icepickle, I am using Redux for state management, so yes, the obj are immutable. This is quite interesting and certainly new to me. Am combing through my code now. Thank you.

Comment: @Icepickle That did it. Unfortunately, I had to remove closure for the sake of localisation of references (optimisatoin). Will think about it and have another go at optimisation another day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expected `svgState` would hold reference to the prop 'svgState'

No. The `svgState` holds the value that `this.props.svgState` had at the time of calling `throttledMouseMoveHandler`. (Of course, that value is an object that references its `.mousemoveState` property)

> … and when `onmousemove` is called, the prop value of `svgState.mousemoveState` would be retrieved from the original obj holding the values.

It is. It will get the current value of the `.mousemoveState` property of the object.

However, if you say that logging `this.props.svgState.mousemoveState` yields `true` while the closure produces `false`, it seems like that someone did change the `.props` or `.svgState` properties to a different object than the closure remembers.

Comment: `No. The svgState holds the value that this.props.svgState had at the time of calling throttledMouseMoveHandler` Just to clarify, are you saying that within the closure `let { svgState } = this.props` is holding the value of `this.props.svgState` instead of storing reference to `this.props.svgState`. That is what I read it as & I believe that is not correct. Please do clarify if I am wrong.

Comment: @Kayote It does hold the value that the property had, but it does not hold a live reference to the property.

Comment: Wouldn't it partly depend on how the props are managed? I mean, as long as props and the object itself stay the same, it will still refer to the same reference, as soon as it doesn't, it's a bit leaky? :)

Comment: @Icepickle Yes, that's exactly what I meant.